# Protractor: how to click link that is said to be not visible

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, protractor

I need to click the link in the page header:

```
<div class="fixed">
        <nav class="top-bar" data-options="is_hover:false">
        ...
        <section class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="left">
                ...
                <li ng-show="hasPermission('ROLE_MESSAGE')" class=""><a href="#/message" class="ng-binding">Message</a></li>
            </ul>
        </section></nav>
</div>
```

But any attempt fails with "Element not visible error". 
It seems strange since on the previous step I've logged on as a user that has the permission ROLE_MESSAGE.
Tried different locators, but none work.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you first need to open up the menu, then click the link:

```
var navigationMenu = element(by.css("nav.top-bar"));
navigationMenu.click();

navigationMenu.element(by.linkText("Message")).click();
```

Or, may be you need to just hover the navigation menu instead of clicking it:

```
var navigationMenu = element(by.css("nav.top-bar"));
browser.actions().mouseMove(navigationMenu).perform();

navigationMenu.element(by.linkText("Message")).click();
```

---

If it doesn't help, you can click the link with javascript, but I would try to avoid that:

```
var navigationMenu = element(by.css("nav.top-bar"));
var messageLink = navigationMenu.element(by.linkText("Message")).click();

browser.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", messageLink);
```